# Position the sublinks outside of the parent

Tags: css

Let's say I have a drop down menu and I was wondering if it's possible to center the menu itself and its sublinks to be positioned with a fixed width so that the sublinks' width doesn't change if the main links are more?

I believe this will explain it better:

[image]

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/georgigyurov/bo1puqon/1/) - Not a working one, but for the sake of explaining.

```
.menu {
position: relative;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 250px;
background-color: #edf7f5;
}
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: blue;
}

.menu li:nth-child(2) ul {
    display: none;
}

    .menu li:nth-child(2) ul li {
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

.menu li:nth-child(2):hover ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code and a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes it is possible but without seeing any code, it's hard to say how to achieve it

Comment: You mean [like this](http://leavesofcode.net/2012/08/30/more-pure-css-menus/)?

Comment: An image speaks 100 languages; a piece of HTML,CSS speaks'em 10000

Comment: @Blazemonger yes, something like that but this is full-width, and if I used pixels for the second ul it won't work

Comment: Here's a not really working fiddle. I can't post the original code because of work policies. http://jsfiddle.net/georgigyurov/bo1puqon/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative;` to the parent and `left: -50%;` to the child `ul` for example

```
.menu li:nth-child(2):hover ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    bottom: -40px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    height:40px;
}
```

make sure the height and the position on the bottom is the same

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bo1puqon/4/)

Comment: If I add more links in the main menu with sublinks, this wouldn't be very effective. I've tried it with left: -50% but it simply doesn't work for me.